# Why my background gradient view is not loading in my customer UINavigationController class

Tags: swift, uiview, background, uinavigationcontroller, gradient

I'm trying to set a gradient to the background of my subclassed NavigationController. When I add a colour to the same code it works well but I can't seem to let my gradient show up. I created a subclass of a UIView that returns a CAGradientLayer as its background view.

Here is my subclassed UIView : (Note the colours are weird so I am sure its loading the right Gradient.

```
@IBDesignable
class GenericBackgrounView: UIView {

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}


///The roundness for the corner
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        setupGradient()
    }
}

func setupGradient() {
    //let gradientColors = [bgDarkColor.cgColor, bgDarkColor.blended(withFraction: 0.5, of: bgLightColor).cgColor, bgLightColor.cgColor]
    let gradientColors = [UIColor.brown.cgColor, UIColor.red.blended(withFraction: 0.5, of: UIColor.cyan).cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = ESDefault.backgroundGradientColorLocations
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupGradient()
}
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    setupGradient()
}

}
```

And Here is my UINavigationController :
    class GenericNavigationController: UINavigationController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backView = GenericBackgrounView(frame: self.view.frame)
    backView.bounds = self.view.bounds
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.view.addSubview(backView)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: backView)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}
```

Also note that my GenericBackgroundView works fine when I use it for any views I add in the interface builder.

I have been at this to long. I think I will suggest to Apple to setup some kind of Theming API in both code and Interface Builder... and the ability to add gradients straight into Interface Builder...

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Don't min the blended(withFraction: 0.5, of: UIColor) function, it's an extension to UIColor that I did to created blended color with a coefficient.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too early to capture the runtime `frame` of a viewController's `view`.  Have you tried printing the frame of the gradient view in the debugger after the view is on screen?  That would likely tell you why it's not on screen.

Comment: I think I may not know enough about the debugger, because I don't quite understand what your trying to tell me.

Comment: OK, so, for example, put a breakpoint at `self.view.addSubview...` in your `viewDidLoad` you pasted above.  When the breakpoint hits it'll freeze the app, and in the debugger at the bottom of Xcode you can type `p backView.frame` and it'll print the frame in the console.  I suspect you'll see that the height/width are 0, or something similar to explain why you're not seeing it on screen.

Comment: Ah ok... I usually use Epressions in the Values windows and I had verified that I was getting the correct frame. None the less, here is the result of the print : print backView.frame
(CGRect) $R2 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 375, height = 667))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it up in `awakeFromNib()` , try calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Reason is that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will have the correct frame of the view , while in `awakeFromNib()` you wouldn't know the right frame of the view.From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews).

Comment: I tried it again just in case but I have the same problem. I had verified that the view's bounds and frame were initialized before I called the function GenericBackgrounView(frame: self.view.frame). I have add similar issues with other types of subclasses of UIView, like the UITableViewCell, and it seems, even though they all subclass UIView, they don't seem to like gradients. I can't apply the same code with all of them. Pfff..

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've tinkered a bit and found some working code. I would still love to understand the reason why this works and not the way I had it before. I hate feeling it works by magic...

here is the working code : (Remember that my gradient is in form of CAGradientLayer and I have made some static variable that has defaults.

```
import UIKit

class GenericNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    let backViewGradient = Default.testGradientCALayer
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupBackground()
    }

    func setupBackground() {
        backViewGradient.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(backViewGradient, at: 0)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setupBackground()
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is how come since all the UIControls that are subclassed from UIView don't all work the same. They should all have a view that is the background and we should all be able to either add a layer or a subview to them and be able to get my previous code to work or my latest code too which does not work with TableViewCells.

I will leave this question open because I would love to know the truth behind this. I don't think I can fully grasp Swift or Xcode if it behaves somewhat magically and inconsistent.

Comment: I just realized, I just lost the capability to see the view custom settings in the Interface Builder...